# Traversing Table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with an HTML attribute on the TR element titled "data-order" which simply holds an integer indicating the order in which to sort the table (descending). Right now the code only checks the row ahead of the TR clicked - what I'm attempting to do is to get it to scan all rows ahead of its position in the table and once it finds a number greater than (not greater than or equal to) then call the swaprow function...

Here is the javascript used to move the row up.

```
function adjustRank(id, e) {
    var url = "/ajax/moveup/" +  aid;
    var row = $(e).closest("tr").get(0);
    var prevRow = $(row).prev().get(0);
    var moveUp = false;
    var prevRowOrder = parseInt($(prevRow).attr("data-order"));
    var rowOrder = parseInt($(row).attr("data-order"));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
        url: url,
        data: {aid: aid},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () 
        { 
            if(rowOrder + 1 > prevRowOrder)  // think this is where I need to traverse the table
                swapRows(row, prevRow);
        },
        failure: function () { alert("Error processing request."); }
    });
}
```

and here are a couple of items in the table for example:

```
<table id="listings" style="min-height:150px; width:100%;">
    <tr id="1" data-order="11"><td>1</td><td align="left"><span onclick="adjustRank('ace93485-cea5-4243-8294-9f3d009aba3d', this)" style="cursor:pointer;">Lindsey Vonn</span></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr id="2" data-order="6"><td>2</td><td align="left"><span onclick="adjustRank('9f83aed6-b99a-4674-a8b7-9f3d009aba38', this)" style="cursor:pointer;">Al Horford</span></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr id="3" data-order="5"><td>3</td><td align="left"><span onclick="adjustRank('d48a52bd-17e9-4631-9a2e-9f3d009aba39', this)" style="cursor:pointer;">Derek Jeter</span></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the AJAX request?  You're not doing anything with the result.  If they are already in order, then why would `swapRows` ever be called?

Comment: Think of it like a voting system. That part works, I'm worried about traversing the table with jquery. Ajax doesn't load the entire result set after the POST is sent. Only a small operation occurs on the ajax call - then the javascript reorders the table on client side to avoid hitting the database or even cache on the server side.  We're optimizing it every where we can.

Comment: Lets start with the very basics: don't use tables for layout. Keep your HTML in `.html` files, your CSS in `.css` files and your JS in `.js` files.

Comment: zzzzBov - this is alredy happending.  Thanks for the input though. As far as tables - they are not always bad IMO (and I'm not the only one - yahoo.com engineers would agree).  This is a list of things that is more suited to a table than any other element.

Comment: I might add that table will not change if page layout changes - it's like a widget. A widget that is already wrapped in a DIV. I stripped some code, etc for brevity in this post.

Comment: You're right, there's a use case for tables and yours might just fit the profile. But I believe @zzzzBov is referring as well to the inline CSS (not really relevant here) and Javascript in your code. If you're already storing data in `data` attributes, why not the ID as well and use jQuery to delegate an click event?

Comment: DOM reading/writing is expensive. A better approach to this issue which would probably also solve your issue in a simpler way, would be to store the data used in the table in a dictionary, sort only this `data representation` when updated and then re–render the table using e.g. JS templates. (An `id` attribute btw. **must not** start with a number.)

Comment: thx polarblau - hmmm... like the suggestion... let me switch that around.  Also, about the inline css (jscript is in a .js file) - I know it's demo code. But hey, if your sug works, drop it as an answer and i'll give you the credit! What about refresh issues?  The list won't ever be over lets say 500? Still expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use recursion to solve that problem. Please, see the code.

```
window.adjustRank = function(id, el) {
    var orderDiff = 1; 
    var row = $(el).closest("tr");
    var order = parseInt(row.attr("data-order")) + orderDiff;
    row.attr("data-order", order);

    var prevRow = row.prev();
    if(prevRow.get(0)){
        moveUp(order, row, prevRow);
    }
}

window.moveUp = function(order, row, prevRow){
    if(order > parseInt(prevRow.attr("data-order"))){
        var prevPrevRow = prevRow.prev();
        if(prevPrevRow.get(0)){
            moveUp(order, row, prevPrevRow);
        } else {
            prevRow.before(row);
        }
    } else {
        prevRow.after(row);
    }
}
```

If you get `orderDiff` via AJAX, then place the code into your AJAX call success function. Please, see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/avrelian/8WRvr/)

Comment: Thanks, this was the tip I needed - added it into my code with some mods and it works great.  There aren't thousands of entries so it's very fast and very efficient.  Also, it doesn't show a refresh of the data like using a collection does (at times). Also, it directly answered my question!